# Umbraco, XSLT, How do I render child content in a parent page?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have content that I've structured as follows in the content section in umbraco:

Items under the content node that have a folder icon are Content Pages.
A content page can have another content page as a child or a content section which are the items with doc with image icon.

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm5.static.flickr.com/4102/4863040077_35f5b131fc.jpg))</sub>

I have a settings section that I've structured as follows:

Each SectionDocumentType has a limited number of available templates the user can select

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm5.static.flickr.com/4075/4863040051_9d36c423f0.jpg))</sub>

What I'd like to do is to render Sections as rows of data in a content page while ignoring child content pages.

I'd like each section "row" to display template and all.

I'm new to XSLT so I'm wondering how could I do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using umbraco 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: Hi Elijah, I'm using Umbraco 4.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out.

Here is the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
     xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets">
   <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/child::*[@isDoc][@nodeType != 1230]">
      <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RenderTemplate(@id,@template)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also I had to add this line to my content section `<umbraco:DisableRequestValidation runat="server"/>` in my content section templates.

Here is how you use it in your page template.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
**<umbraco:DisableRequestValidation runat="server"/>** 
**YOUR HTML GOES HERE**
</asp:Content>​
```